# Performing stop of activity that is not resumed - Android

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I am getting this error: Performing stop of activity that is not resumed LoginActivity. I have read the other threads about this error but I still can`t see what is the problem.

Here is my Logcat:

```
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {package/package.LoginActivity}
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3333)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3420)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:161)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And my Activity:

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
 EditText edtMail,edtPass;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    Button regButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.registerbtn);
    Button logButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);

    final Context context = getApplicationContext();
    edtMail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    edtPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pword);
    // testing if GooglePlayServices works//TODO
    if(GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this) ==  ConnectionResult.SUCCESS )
        System.out.println("Google PLAY SERVICES");


    //getting specs for device //TODO
    HashMap<String, String> specsHash = new HashMap<String, String>();
    GetSpecs getSpecs = new GetSpecs(this);
    specsHash = getSpecs.getAllSpecs();
    for (Map.Entry<String,String> entry : specsHash.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        String value = entry.getValue();
        System.out.println(key + " = " + value);
    }


    //check device camera
    boolean hasCamera = CheckDeviceCamera.isDeviceSupportCamera(context);

    //check device GPS
    boolean hasGPS = CheckDeviceGPS.isDeviceSupportGPS(context);

    //if have details try to log the user in
    if (new SharedPrefsMemo().getPrefs(context) == 1) {
        DatabaseConnector databaseConnector = new DatabaseConnector(context);
        //gasire: 0->nimic gasit, 1->gasit agent; 2->gasit asistent
        int gasire = databaseConnector.loadInregistrare(Prefs.emailPref, Prefs.parolaPref);
        if (gasire != 0) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("tip", gasire);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    }


    //register button
    regButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, RegisterSplitActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    logButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String password = edtPass.getText().toString();
            String email = edtMail.getText().toString();

            DatabaseConnector databaseConnector = new DatabaseConnector(context);

            int gasire = databaseConnector.loadInregistrare(email, password);
            if(gasire != 0 ) {
                SharedPrefsMemo sharedPrefsMemo = new SharedPrefsMemo();

                if(gasire == 1) {
                    sharedPrefsMemo.memoPrefs(GetObiecte.agent.email, GetObiecte.agent.parola, GetObiecte.agent.id,
                                             context);
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    myIntent.putExtra("tip", gasire);
                    startActivity(myIntent);

                }

                else
                    if(gasire == 2) {
                        sharedPrefsMemo.memoPrefs(GetObiecte.asistent.email, GetObiecte.asistent.parola,
                                                    GetObiecte.asistent.id, context);
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        myIntent.putExtra("tip", gasire);
                        startActivity(myIntent);

                    }


            }
           else  {
                CharSequence text = "Date de logare gresite!";
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                toast.show();
            }
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //activare GPS//TODO
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if(!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        //Ask the user to enable GPS
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Location Manager");
        builder.setMessage("Activate GPS?");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //Launch settings, allowing user to make a change
                Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //No location service, no Activity
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Activate the GPS", duration);
                toast.show();
                finish();
            }
        });
        builder.create().show();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: try to comment the finish(); in onResume.. then run and see if it still gives the error/

Comment: Write the code for GPS enabling in the method onCreate() instead of onResume() by commenting finish().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and the answer by @sheetal solved my issue.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23246159/4871489

> The issue will still be there on all HighEnd phones with 4.4.2 and
>   above including NEXUS 5,Samsumg s4 since onResume gets called but
>   still it is in animation stage.So if you try to start a activity in
>   onResume the issue will replicate.

I created a handler to start my intent with a small delay and the issue disappeared.

Hope it helps

Comment: Great. Thanks. It seems to be an issue with higher Android APIs as you said