# java.lang.RuntimeException: Performing stop of activity that is not resumed

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, runtimeexception

i'm trying to show an activity (introduction `activity`) appears only once this `activity` contains one `Button` (**Skip**), when user click in **skip** `button` `MainActivity` will showing so for that i use `SharedPreference` when i run my app on android 6.0 or 7.0 works fine but when i run it on android 5.0.1 ( Samsung S4 ) the **skip** `button` works but not in a smooth way he keep stuck for a while(3 or 4 seconds ) .

**Logcat** :

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Performing stop of activity that is not
>   resumed:
>   {com.android.settings/com.android.settings.applications.InstalledAppDetails}

**Intro Activity :**

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            setContentView(R.layout.introactivity);
            skip = (Button)findViewById(R.id.skip);
            hide();
            appPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            skip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = appPreferences.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("introSkipped", true);
                    editor.apply();
                    finish();
                }
            });
        }
```

**MainActivity :**

```
SharedPreferences appPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        if (!appPreferences.getBoolean("introSkipped", false)) {
            Intent toIntro = new Intent(this, introactivity.class);
            startActivity(toIntro);
        }
```

Comment: Your problem is witth exception or with time taking on skiping

Comment: @AbdulWaheed with time taking to skipping

Comment: This will not solve your problem but it is always a good idea to explicitly name the activity you want to finish with IntroActivity.this.finish().

Comment: Where are you calling the startActivity(IntroActivityIntent) in? In onResume() of MainActivity? Maybe you have a loop here! Please extend your code snippets.

Comment: @botzek13 for the time being i don't use `onResume()` for calling `startActivity(toIntro);`

Comment: @botzek13 i tried to call `SharedPreferences appPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        if (!appPreferences.getBoolean("introSkipped", false)) {
            Intent toIntro = new Intent(this, useheadphone.class);
            startActivity(toIntro);
        }` in `onResume()`  and i have the same problem

Comment: Please check with getDefaultSharedPreferencesName if the SharedPrefs are one and the same for IntroActivity.context and MainActivity.context. But I think the problem is the moment of starting your IntroActivity. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/23246159/4871489 and try the Handler-version of delayed starting of the IntroActivity.

Comment: @botzek13 thanks i checked it and  i have the same name